# No visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexpath:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm new to programing and have been working one "start developing IOS apps today" guide from apple. i got to the 3rd section *tutorial: add data* when i came across the error in the title, it effecting the part of the code. the error is on the line starting with *UITableViewCell *cell*

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListPrototypeCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexpath:indexPath];
    StuffItem *toDoItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = toDoItem.itemName;
    return cell;
}
```

i have done my best to follow all the instruction from the guide up until this point, and my only guess of a problem could be that i named my files differently than it suggested.

Comment: The "p" in indexPath must be uppercase.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you only problem is capitalization of Index **P** ath, in the future you can just tab after the first couple letters and let XCode expand out the full name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier 
      forIndexpath:indexPath];
              ^
```

should be

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier 
      forIndexPath:indexPath];
              ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note on Xcode.... within Xcode, the error will be flagged by a red circle in the leftmost margin. Also, there will be a little caret presented under the offending item. My guess is you have a caret under forIndexpath as others have mentioned and illustrated. Also, by clicking on the red circle Xcode will provide you with a little more info helping you narrow the problem. The final clue is the error itself, it indicates "No visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexpath:". A 'selector' in objective-c is essentially a method if we were to use c/c++ terminology. The error indicates that there is no method named "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexpath:" for class "UITableView". That is your clue to check 1) your spelling, 2) that you are using the correct selectors for the correct classes.